# JavaFX - Change coordinates of ImageView on click

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview

I'm creating a Chess App and i can't figure out how to move an **ImageView** from its current position to another. Let me start from the begin.

My main design used to look like this : http://prntscr.com/i98pfc.
But when i add the pieces to a pane/tile, I can't click the area that the piece lies, only the rest of the tile. I have an EventHandler for the panes. It gives me pane's coordinates - represented as in 2D array - when i click on it. But when i click at the area of the piece nothing happens. No coordinates shown. Example: http://prntscr.com/i98xi2.

I'm adding a new tile with a piece on it, like that.

```
tiles[1][0] =  new Tile(1, 0, new Pawn  (0, "/.resources/Chess_pdt60.png"));
tiles[1][1] =  new Tile(1, 1, new Pawn  (0, "/.resources/Chess_pdt60.png"));
tiles[1][2] =  new Tile(1, 2, new Pawn  (0, "/.resources/Chess_pdt60.png"));



grid.add(new ImageView(new Image(tiles[1][0].getPieceOnTile().getImage())), 0, 1);
```

I'm adding the tile to the board with the upper line. As you see i add a ***new ImageView(...)*** and the problem i described to you above occurs. I found out mouse click events don't work with **ImageView**.

I tried removing one pane and replacing it with ImageView from the fxml and it worked. I even click the piece and i get its coordinates.

> Main Question :

I want to replace every pane with an ImageView. But then how could i move a piece ?

Comment: ImageViews boards arent the best approach to make an kind of game, you need to draw it on Graphics2D. Else, you better to use ImageButtons and replace items with two clicks.

Comment: But for your case, you have two cases: the main container may listen all events in MouseListener or all childs have a listener for its click (but this way you will need to fire events for the main container)

Comment: 1) by childs you mean panes ? If yes, what will change? there still will be the image of the piece.
2) what is the main container?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos You're aware this is a JavaFX question, right? What is a `MouseListener`?

Comment: We can't really answer this question without quite a lot more detail. How is your `Tile` class implemented, for example? What is the nature of your images (all the same size with transparency, etc)? "Mouse clicks don't work with `ImageView`" is not an accurate statement. See if you can create a simplified example which is complete, does enough to demonstrate the problem, but nothing more than that (see [MCVE]).

Comment: The equivalent is also true for JavaFX, or the container listen or the child (each Tile) for dragging is better the container

Comment: I agree. But in general it's a fact that ImageView doesn't support mouse clicks. Should i use another pane? I'm currently using BorderPane and inside an anchor pane with some Hbox/Vbox. The anchor pane includes a GridPane as well with panes in it, as i described. Should i use a different type of Pane?

Comment: @A.Tressos "In general it's a fact that `ImageView` doesn't support mouse clicks."  No - this is not true. You can register an event handler for mouse events with an `ImageView` and, unless there are specific reasons otherwise, it will fire those events.

Comment: I 've already created this handler. But we need to trigger this handler at every click on the grid. Eg. when we click the queen, i store to an ImageView its image, i should sth like queen_image.setHandler(...) ... but what about the other ? should i create an ImageView for every tile ? this is so bad ... i know i have been thinking something completely wrong

Comment: Hmm. Again, we don't really know how you are trying to implement this. I would have an `ImageView` per piece (so 8 `ImageView` instances for the white pawns at the beginning of the game, etc; they can share the same actual `Image` instance to save memory). Register the mouse handlers with the `ImageView`s. Or you could do it differently: place a `Pane` in each cell in the grid, make the `ImageView`s mouse transparent, and register mouse handlers with the `Pane`s, etc. It's not really clear what you're asking at this stage.

Comment: and yes images are all the same size 100 x 100, with transparent background

Comment: I understand, but it will be soo messy if i posted my code here. The important thing is that i have a class Tile : that has a pieceOnTile field and coordinates x,y. I initialize my tile just like i showed you. I have a piece class that takes constructor arguements: a player and an ImageView of its image. I m currently initializing my ImageView s just like that : ImageView dark_pawn1 = new ImageView(path); etc.
AND rook, knight, pawn, queen, king, bishop extends Piece class.